# How to execute a maven-plugin only with custom command?

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I'm using `xsdtojava` with `cxf` maven` plugin:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                   <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
       </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Question: I want to prevent executing this plugin on every `mvn package`. Instead, I only want to trigger the source generation manually. But how? I tried setting a custom phase or goal like `<phase>generate-sources-now</phase>` or `<goal>generate-sources-now</goal>`, but did does not work.

Comment: Tried setting up the plugin under one specific profile?

Comment: No. How could I tie a plugin to a profile?

Comment: Well, just declare a profile, and add the plugin to it. It will only run when mvn is called with the profile... `<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>special</id>
  <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
     <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
     ...
     </executions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
 </profile>
</profiles>` the run `mvn -Pspecial <goals>` (as far as I know)

Comment: I would also go with a separate profile. You would need to run maven with that profile (for example `-Pxsdtojava`), or bind it to some activation property.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'd prefer a maven goal approach, the profile approach works as suggested:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>xsdtojava</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>

                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>

                        <configuration>
                             .....
```

Run with: `mvn package -P xsdtojava`

Answer (score 0):

Plugins don't need to have executions.

Just configure you plugin as

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
   ...
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and call the goal in the usual `:` notation (`cxf-xjc-plugin:goal`).

Comment: Could I also somehow execute the `xsdtojava` goal directly?

Comment: I tried `mvn cxf-xjc-plugin:xsdtojava`, but getting an error: `No plugin found for prefix 'cxf-xjc-plugin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/user/.m2/repository)`

Comment: Ok, you probably need something like `org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:1.2.3:goal`

Comment: Adding the plugin configuration to `<pluginManagement>` should allow you to use the short form, but I am not completely sure. Note that `1.2.3` need to be replaced by the version you want.

Comment: `mvn org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava` fails with `Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.0:xsdtojava (default-cli) on project namedquery-ws: Must specify xsdOptions`. So it seems my existing configuration is not taken from the `pom.xml` in thise case

Comment: Ok, I got it working with `mvn org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:xsdtojava` when moving the `<configuration/>` out of the `<execution/>` tag. BUT: when running `mvn package` the `xsdtojava` goal is still executed. That's not what I want...

Comment: You need to completely remove the `<execution>` block.